# Selecting by attributes which have alphabet data using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, select-by-attribute

I only want to select values that are entirely alphabetic characters.

Select by attributes which I have alphabet data.

**SELECT ONLY RED INDICATED VALUES**

[image]

Comment: Can it contain whitespaces and special charachters like .,!? and if so do you want to select? Or only letters

Comment: only letters like A-Z and a-z

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour]

Comment: I'd probably use a cursor for this. Or calculate a new field that matches only the values with alphabetic characters and then select all non-null values

Comment: @rakesreddyposham please [edit] your question to include any additional information (rather than commenting).  What have you tried?  Can you give some examples of your existing data?

Comment: Doesn’t one of those red strings (VFG2) have a number in it?

Answer (score 5):

Use arcpy and check each row of the table using da.SearchCursor and list ObjectIDs of the rows matching your condition. Then select using the list. Adjust and execute in python window:

```py
import arcpy

layer = 'somelayeraddedtothemap' #Change
field_to_check = 'somefield' #Change

oidfield = arcpy.Describe(layer).OIDFieldName #What is the oid fieldname

#List oids of rows with only letters
oids_to_select = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,[oidfield, field_to_check]) as cursor:
    for oid, somestring in cursor:
        if somestring.isalpha(): #isalpha is true only if all char are letters
            oids_to_select.append(oid)

#Select
sql = "{0} IN{1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(layer, oidfield), tuple(oids_to_select))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute(in_layer_or_view=layer, where_clause=sql)
```